# Spring Boot AWS Elastic Beanstalk - nginx error Connection refused http://127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Spring Boot application to Elastic AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However the deployment is always in a "Severe" state, with the below being logged into /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.241, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

172.31.12.137 - the IP of the EC2 instance

I'm aware that I need to change the server port to 5000 and I have done that in my application.properties file and from the logs I can see that the application has launched on port 5000

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
```

I'm connecting to a MYSQL database on RDS and I can confirm that the application is connecting successfully to that database.

Is there a configuration setting I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated

FYI: I'm not very experienced with AWS

Answer (score 2):

Try using port 8080. You can set `SERVER_PORT` to `8080` from the Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot application You should add the property server.port=5000  in your application.properties file and also if you are using a profile based property file add the environment variable in the configurations as SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod for your profile based property file to be used during run time.

[image]